# Blob Para bitmap retorna nulo apenas no Android 4.2.2

Tags: android, bitmap

É simples, se eu usar essa linha de código no android 5.0 , 6.0 ela funciona corretamente, e converte o blob em bitmap. Porém, testando aqui em um aparelho inferior (android 4.2.2 ) ela sempre retorna null;

```
private Bitmap blotToBit(Blob blob) {
    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inSampleSize = 4;
    return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(blob.getBinaryStream(), null, options);
}
```

Uma simples linha de log é exibida para cada tentativa :

```
D/skia: --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
```

Note, que as bitmaps são de 256x256 será que já são muito grandes ?

**Obs** . já tentei fazer usando apenas 1 blob , e ainda sim , não converte

Comment: Rodrigo, checou se do banco não está voltando um Blob nulo? Como sugestão use outra abordagem e armazene em String Base64 e convertê-la em Bitmap. Isso tem uma série de vantagens. Inclusive por exemplo, cifrar a imagem para guardar no banco, transmitir pela rede etc.

Comment: Sim já verifiquei, eu estou usando o mesmo banco em todos os SOs. E o blob não é nulo !

Comment: Opa, Rodrigo, acredito que se ao inves de usar o tipo "Blob" voce pegasse a imagem como uma string hex e convertece ela para uma imagem usando bytearray voce teria mais sucesso nisso.
aqui tem um bom exemplo [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10143135/hex-string-to-image]

Comment: convertece ou convertesse? sou pessimo em portugues, ririri

Comment: a pior parte é que funciona em outros sistemas , mas não existe warming nenhum de api